# pygtk+: How to display a second image 3 seconds after the first?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I am writing a pygtk+ program that would allow a user to navigate thru a book by using buttons in a toolbar.
On opening the program, I would like to display a "title" or "cover page" image for a few seconds while the GUI is completed. Then a background image would be displayed.
This script only displays the second image after a delay of 3s.

```
import gi, time
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class FirstScrn(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        image = Gtk.Image.new_from_file("../images/first.png")
        self.add(image)
        self.show_all()
        time.sleep(3)
        self.remove(image)
        image = Gtk.Image.new_from_file("../images/second.png")
        self.add(image)
        self.show_all()

first = FirstScrn()
first.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

Gtk.main()
```

How could I achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Be sure to read about [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sometime.

Comment: Since you are using Python3 and Gtk3, you would actually tag your question as PyObject.

Comment: @theGtknerd : it works. Thanks a lot! - eole77

Comment: Good. Please mark it accepted by clicking the checkmark beside my answer. It will give me reputation and anybody else looking at this post will know it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a possible solution:

```
import gi, time
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib

class FirstScrn(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        image = Gtk.Image.new_from_file("../images/first.png")
        self.add(image)
        self.show_all()
        GLib.timeout_add_seconds(3, self.show_next_image, image)

    def show_next_image (self, previous_image):
        self.remove(previous_image)
        image = Gtk.Image.new_from_file("../images/second.png")
        self.add(image)
        self.show_all()

first = FirstScrn()
first.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

Gtk.main()
```

Remember, time.sleep will make Gtk unresponsive. And threads don't work either. That is why you use things like [timeout_add](https://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html#function-glib--timeout-add) and [idle_add](https://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html#function-glib--idle-add).